# Java XML Logging within tags

Tags: java, filehandler

I'm trying to generate an XML log that logs messages one after the other, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
   <message>Message 1</message>
   <message>Message 2</message>
   //Next messages to append here
</log>
```

I've looked at various solutions but none seem to work as I require.
The closest i've come is using the following: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html

I've tweaked it to work to my needs, i.e.

```
public String format(LogRecord rec) {
  StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(1000);
  buf.append('\n');
  buf.append(formatMessage(rec));
  buf.append('\n')
  return buf.toString() ;
}
public String getHead(Handler h) {
 return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<log>";
}
public String getTail(Handler h) {
  return "</log>";
}
```

The problem with this is that getTail isn't called until my FileHandler is closed, so its only valid when it is closed.

I've closed it and tried reopening the FileHandler with append = true for the next message, but this (not surprisingly) appends to the end of the log.
e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
   <message>Message 1</message>
</log>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
   <message>Message 2</message>
</log>
```

This feels like it should be really simple...

Comment: Unless you want to play games with random-access file writing, so you can overwrite the document element's end-tag with the new log item and a new end tag, or are willing to accept the Document Fragment approach, you may simply have to settle for the output not being well-formed XML until your program exits.

Answer (score 0):

[http://logback.qos.ch/][logback] is latest logging system in xml format. 
   You can log your error, debug, trace and info level information.
   You can specify file name for every day to log.
   Below mentioned an example that cover these things.

```
 <configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/mnt/resource/fe/frontend.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>/mnt/resource/fe/frontend-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date - [%level] - %message%xException%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```